# Inputstream starts with a -1

Tags: java, cxf, inputstream, attachment

When a file is uploaded with a slow connection (only), using my CXF REST API, I get `Couldn't find MIME boundary` error. So I debugged the CXF core code to find why. Now I'm looking at this CXF Core code[1].

```
    private static boolean readTillFirstBoundary(PushbackInputStream pbs, byte[] bp) throws IOException {

        // work around a bug in PushBackInputStream where the buffer isn't
        // initialized
        // and available always returns 0.
        int value = pbs.read();
        pbs.unread(value);
        while (value != -1) {
            value = pbs.read();
```

When the client to server connection is very slow, the first value of the input stream is almost always `-1`. That results `Couldn't find MIME boundary` error at the later on the flow.

If I change the code to skip the first byte if it's -1 like below, it works smoothly.

```
    private static boolean readTillFirstBoundary(PushbackInputStream pbs, byte[] bp) throws IOException {

        // work around a bug in PushBackInputStream where the buffer isn't
        // initialized
        // and available always returns 0.
        int value = pbs.read();
        if (value == -1) {                <<<<<< if the first byte is -1,
            value = pbs.read();           <<<<<< ignore that and read the  
        }                                 <<<<<< next byte
        pbs.unread(value);
        while (value != -1) {
            value = pbs.read();
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

[1] https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.2.8/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/attachment/AttachmentDeserializer.java#L264

Comment: -1 means the stream is empty, of course, and you certainly shouldn't push back -1, but I don't understand why you are doing this at all. There are few if any correct uses of `available()`, and I doubt that whatever you're doing with it is one of them.

Comment: If you look at the code closely, I don't push back -1. After the very first byte which is -1, the content I want is there. I just skipped the first byte to read the rest. It's not a proper fix. I'm just trying to understand why it happens.

Comment: Updated the description to make the question more clear.

Comment: Can you show an example of the response message with the attachment you are trying to parse?

Comment: It throws a 500. I don't get a response as it throws `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryUpaV4aL1pPB20eyP` error.

Comment: The first byte is not -1. The first *value returned* by `read()` is -1, which is a sentinel value indicating end of stream. It is not a data byte. If you look at your own code more closely you will see that your first code sample pushes back -1 if it occurs. If there is data after you read -1 there is something seriously wrong with your `PushBackInputStream`: probably that you have made this same mistake elsewhere. You still haven't stated why you care about the behaviour of `available()`, and BTW the problem you allege with it is non-existent.

Comment: `The first byte is not -1. The first value returned by read() is -1` yes, this part is correct. Did you go through the question after I updated? The code is not mine. It's cxf core. I only added 3 lines (which is shown by `<<<<`) just to debug. `If there is data after you read -1 there is something seriously wrong with your PushBackInputStream: ` this is exactly what I'm looking for. I actually removed the PushBackInputStream wrapper and checked. The Inputstream itself gives this -1. I know, it very strange. And the reason of which exactly I'm looking for. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Do you think it can be the end of the previous stream, for some reason?

Comment: It's a bug in their code, possibly several. Report it to them. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Yeah, most probably. I'm wondering what my API does differently to experience the bug, why not it's common. It can't find the same behavior reported anywhere in the internal. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: My wild guess is their `read` method uses timeout and when that timeout hits, they return -1. I suggest you to debug deeper into that `read` method. Their stream implementation seems buggy.

Comment: It turned out to be a tomcat bug. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a tomcat bug[1]. :-/

Works file with later Tomcat versions.

[1] https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64195